# Neither :method => :post and :remote => true is working on my Rails 3.1 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

The HTML that is rendered seems right:

```
<a href="/foo/add" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow"><img src=/assets/icons/example.png></a>
```

Inspite of the data-method and data-remote both being rendered, when I click the link, the browser seems to issue a GET because Rails complains about a lack of a route. I do want this to be a POST but I went ahead and added a GET in routes.rb and the call works but is now is a regular call rather than an AJAX call. I seem to be missing some JS file somewhere... very new to Rails 3.1 - can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `Gemfile` has this:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and that your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` has this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
```

and that your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` contains these 2 lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

These parts are all needed to properly use the `:remote` options in Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dylan. I do havethe line in my gemfile, I do have the line in layout and my application.js has those two lines (as also a third line //= require_tree . The behavior is unchanged, the browser still does a GET instead of a POST and even if i add GET to routes.rb, then the call is not an AJAX call.. what else am I missing?

Comment: I carefully followed the instructions over here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1

Things work as expected now.